How do I disable repeating keys on Windows 11?
So I'm using AnyDesk to remotely access a Macbook from my Windows device. I'm using my Mac to make music. Unfortunately, my MIDI keyboard isn't being recognized as a device (which is an entirely different problem altogether) so I'm stuck with using just the normal computer keyboard to play in notes. However, when I hold down the keys, they repeat after a short delay. This is very annoying and impractical.
Filter Keys isn't the solution here. I've fiddled with Keyboard Properties and there is no option to turn off key repeating, only a delay and rate slider (why???) I even tried disabling it on the Macbook end (it's remarkably straight forward and simple on a Mac) to no avail.
Is there something I'm missing? Is there even like a third-party software I can download? Is this just an AnyDesk issue (I've had little luck with VNCs and TeamViewer doesn't transmit audio from Macs)? I don't know what to do.

What didn't work when you tried "Filter Keys" -> "Turn on Repeat Keys and Slow Keys" -> "Set up Repeat Keys and Slow Keys" -> "Ignore all repeated keystrokes"?

Ignoring all repeated keystrokes seems to be something that is specifically tailored to faulty hardware. The key isn't repeatedly being pressed, but it's registering multiple key presses automatically, which is a standard behavior. What i want is to be able to do is to hold down any key and have that correspond to one key press, and fliter keys doesn't do that as far as I'm aware.

Oh, it looks like for Windows 11 you have to enable the icon for Filter Keys, hold the right shift key until Filter Keys starts, and then you can get to "Set up Repeat Keys and Slow Keys" via the icon. It was easier in Windows 10.
